# Ungrade Lenovo T500 to 22.04 fails. Boots into "emergency Mode". Install from live CD does boot OK

Tags: boot, upgrade

On a Lenovo T500 laptop, I upgraded from 20.04 to 22.04.
On boot after upgrade, it boots into "emergency mode".

I then installed Ubuntu 22.04 from the Live USB on a different partition, and that
boots successfully so this would seem to mean that there is not a hardware compatibility problem. I have upgraded several other systems (all x140e) from 20.04 to 22.04 successfully.

The output of the sysjournal -xb command doesn't show any obvious errors. The last lines of the journal are:

```
░░ Subject: A start job for unit NetworkManager-dispatcher.service has finished successfully
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░ 
░░ A start job for unit NetworkManager-dispatcher.service has finished successfully.
░░ 
░░ The job identifier is 239497.
Jul 18 04:51:39 earl dbus-daemon[741]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Jul 18 04:51:39 earl systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
░░ Subject: A start job for unit NetworkManager-dispatcher.service has begun execution
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░ 
░░ A start job for unit NetworkManager-dispatcher.service has begun execution.
░░ 
░░ The job identifier is 239497.
Jul 18 04:51:39 ea
```

Which are similar to what is in the journal for the fresh install that boots successfully. What should I be looking for for why the upgraded version boots into
emergency mode?

Other tips to find why the upgrade boots to emergency mode?

Comment: can you do `systemctl --failed` and post output? also maybe try updating grub from live USB just in case

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I did not know about the --failed option. In "messing" (trying to start NetworkManager from command line, trying startx, using Ctl/Alt/F2 or F3 to get a separate window..) I had strange and unreproducable behavior including the network starting once and and once the system amazingly went into full operation and I could login the desktop and all was well. But nothing was reproducable. For now I needed to get work done and restored my 20.04 system and will try again in a month or so - remembering your idea should it fail again.